# CSS Dropdown Disappears When Focus From Parent <li> is lost

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I've read replies for similar problems to mine, and I believe I've tried the steps mentioned but I'm still having problems with my dropdown menu disappearing when mouse off.

I've removed the formatting of the dropdown just so the code is bare bones, please take a look:

http://freerange.wesleypearce.co.uk

If you mouse over past productions you'll see my problem.

Thanks in advance for what probably is quite a simple fix, it's just alluding me!

Cheers,

Wes.

Comment: check the answer and let me know if i am lagging some where...

Comment: Hey do you check my answer? Please let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rule for your dropdown uls, use `padding-top: <#>px;` rather than `top: 45px;` to put spacing between the menu header and your list.  The `top` value should be no more than the height of the menu header, otherwise you'll create a gap between it and the list, which will remove the list's visibility as soon as the cursor moves off the header and over the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on style.css line 89

I have changed the top position of ul. The problem is there is a gap between your `a tag` (Past Products) and dropdown `ul`

```
#menu ul ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing your submenu too far from your main menu item, just declare it `100%` to push your submenu exactly below your main menu item to fix the problem:

```
#menu ul ul {
    top: 100%; /* fix */
}
```